# Sympy pretty print matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math, pretty-print

I am using sympy to do symbolic matrix multiplication of 13 2x2 matrices (for optics). The resulting matrix is of course a 2x2 matrix but is huge.

I am using `pprint()` in order to display stuff in a nice manner.
Problem is that pprint is basically "splitting" the matrix over many rows making it basically unreadable. To put things into perspective, below is the first element of the matrix as it is pretty printed, so imagine how the whole thing is going to look like.

[image]

Any tips, tricks to pretty print the matrix in a continuous way?

Many thanks,

P.S; I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: In Jupyter you can use the LaTeX rendering rather than pprint. The `pprint` function is intended for printing nicely in a terminal window - if you were using a terminal then you could "solve" this problem by making the window large and the font small.

Comment: I don't see how a complicated sympy expression like that can be displayed in a readable manner.  I use `isympy`, `ipython` with `sympy.init_printing()`.  It still wraps large expressions to the window size.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little late. After over an hour searching for this tiny problem, I finally found a fix: As stated in their [internal documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.pretty.pretty.pretty_print) for pretty_print (pprint is essentially a wrapper for this):

```py
num_columns : int or None, optional (default=None)
        Number of columns before line breaking (default to None which reads
        the terminal width), useful when using SymPy without terminal.
```

I would recommend setting the limit to something you will never exceed, e.g. 10,000 or even 100,000. This at least worked for me:

```py
pprint(expression, num_columns=10_000)
```